# How do I prevent certain elements from loading in until they're in my viewport?

Tags: php, html, css, optimization, tailwind-css

I have page where there's gonna be 1000+ images. They're separated into different photography projects so you just scroll down and look through them. However, all (135 at the moment) the images cache at once so it's slow, even though the images are down-scaled 75% from original size. I load in the images dynamically with PHP to make it easier for my client to expand their portfolio with minimal code editing.

I'm looking for something that Pinterest uses. It doesn't load in the images (or previews) until you've scrolled to them and they're actually visible in the viewport.

Dynamic PHP code:

```
$dir = ("projects/photography/" . scandir("projects/photography/")[$photographyIndex]);
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $file) {
    if($file !== "." && $file !== ".." && $file !== "info.php") {
        echo "<img src='$dir/$file' class='h-full' />";
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're looking for is lazy loading. Try using `loading="lazy"` attributes on your `<img>` tags. Alternatively, you could use external javascript libraries to achieve this, such as lozad.js, or code it on your own using JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Ownagin!

The problem was that I didn't have `loading="lazy"` on my `<img>` tags. I was aware of this being a thing, but never bothered to apply it because I read it was enabled by default.

```
$dir = ("projects/photography/" . scandir("projects/photography/")[$photographyIndex]);
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $file) {
    if($file !== "." && $file !== ".." && $file !== "info.php") {
        echo "<img src='$dir/$file' class='h-full' loading='lazy' />";
    }
}
```